# case when statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting an error saying an expression of non boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, what is wrong with the statement?

```
CASE WHEN (TEAR.REASONS_FOR_TEARDOWN IN (21,17) 
           AND (SELECT COUNT(ELEMENTNAME) 
                  FROM EINSPECTION_TABLE T 
                        INNER JOIN EINSPECTION_MAIN M 
                              ON T.ELEMENTID=M.ELEMENTID 
                 WHERE ELEMENTTYPE = 'TD' 
                   AND ENGINEID=1650 
                   AND STATUS IN (1126,1127))>1) 
     THEN 'YC'
```

Comment: Do you `end` your `case` expression in the rest of your code?

Comment: would help if you show us where that case expression is used

Comment: @Stephen beat me by seconds with the same comment :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to `end` your `case` expression. Optionally include an `else`.

```
case when (TEAR.REASONS_FOR_TEARDOWN in (21, 17) 
        and (
          select COUNT(ELEMENTNAME)
          from EINSPECTION_TABLE T
            inner join EINSPECTION_MAIN M 
              on T.ELEMENTID = M.ELEMENTID
          where ELEMENTTYPE = 'TD' 
            and ENGINEID = 1650 
            and status in (1126, 1127)
            ) > 1
          ) 
      then 'YC'
    else null
    end
```

Comment: I have put an end case to the last condition but its still the same, the query above is the second case, hence didnt mention END case

Comment: @Reddy Please post the whole statement in an edit to your question.

Answer (score -1):

case when (TEAR.REASONS_FOR_TEARDOWN IN ('21', '17')

Also you need an end statement for the case

Comment: REASONS_FOR_TEARDOWN is numeric ,even if I put quotes it throws an error and also i have put an end statement in my query.

Comment: There is no indication of the type of the field `REASONS_FOR_TEARDOWN` for your suggestion to add single quotes on it. Also, it is not a complete answer as per your suggestion as SqlZim added on his.